# Laravel : custom naming for relation many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got a case where all my users are in a table, but managers are into too and I need to name the model Manager even if they are stored in table users, how can I deal with that ?
The simplest way to identyfy Managers could be by adding a simple flag in table User ?

Comment: Add an additional field in your table, yes.

Comment: the table should not be nammed user_service ? I would name it manager_service it will create problems ?

Comment: If you change the table's name you need to change the name everywhere else it's being used. So it's not a problem, if you know what you're doing.

Comment: I think it's not good to create confusion about the nature of the relation in namming it service_user my users have just one service, but managers can manage many services. How would you deal with that ?